# How to set navigation option menu as icon button instead on title text

Tags: android, navigation

I can set the option menu to navigation fragment.

```
class NavigationtFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        ...
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        // set the option menu
    }
}
```

Is it possible to replace it with the add icon button?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to show menu in fragment? Can you give more details?

Comment: Basically it need to add the menu xml file and then config it to the fragment, check the navigation chapter of the official guide on the udacity https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012 to find more detail.

Comment: Added my answer, try it and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create menu.xml file and add the icon above you have shown.

```
android:icon="@drawable/add_icon"
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_menu_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_icon"
        android:title="@string/my_menu_item_title"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Now in your fragment:

```
class NavigationtFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        ...
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        // set the option menu
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.my_menu_item -> {
                // Add your action
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Now your menu shows up. Make sure you have your activity setup properly with NavController, if not your menu will not show up in Toolbar. You can do this way.

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

Comment: `app:showAsAction="always"` is the point to my question, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_add);
        toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
```

Comment: Is it just replace the menu icon to add icon? Can let it work as a button and not a menu button?